# Prevent about:blank tab from opening, should send user straight to specified URL without delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, url-routing

My intention is to send the user to a new tab instead of redirecting on the current page. I am doing this in a function in react, but `onClick` of the element, a new tab opens but starts at about:blank and takes almost 5 seconds to actually start loading the actual URL. How can I prevent `about:blank` from appearing and just loading the URL first? (I can't use `target="_blank"` because the HTML element is dynamically rendered).

Code is below:

```
openTab(){
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      const id = getSelectedIds(getState)[0];
      const reroute = `${baseRoute}/insights/${id}`
      open(reroute);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the target attribute of [open](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/open):

```
open(reroute, '_blank');
```

If it's not working you can try creating a `<a>` element, assign the url and target attributes and click it:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.target = "_blank";
    a.href = reroute;
    a.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

create an `a` tag and edit the target attribute.

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.target = "_blank"
```

This will always work to open any kind of link in a new tab, with as little delay as possible with webpage loading times.